# Assist copying items (folder & file) to remote computer within a remote session

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I wrote a script to do some folder/file checks on remote servers (looping through them). If a folder doesn't exist, I want to copy it from a remote share to the computer I'm currently 'in session' to in the loop. My whole script works, I tested, except for copying a folder & file from
a remote share to the computer session I'm in. Can you all share where I'm going wrong in my Copy-Item command?...or even suggest alternative solutions? Below is my code. I left out details, but shared the most important pieces. Let me know if you need more. Thanks!

```
$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Test,OU=2ndOUT,DC=domain,DC=com" | Select Name -ExpandProperty Name
$user = "domain\user"
$pwd = "pwd"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $pwd

foreach ($server in $servers) {
   $psSession = New-PSSession -Computername $server -Credential $cred
   $psSession
   $file = "C:\path\to\file"

   Invoke-Command  -Session $psSession -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {
      if (-Not (Test-Path $Using:file -PathType Leaf)) {

     $folder = "C:\folder\path"
     if (-Not (Test-Path $folder)) {

        write-host "folder doesn't exist, so need to copy it from remote to local session server
        $remoteFolder = "\\path\to\remote\server\folder"
        $remoteFile = "\\path\to\remote\server\file"
        $destinationPath = "C:\folder\on\session\server"

        Copy-Item -Path $filePath -Destination $destinationPath -FromSession $Using:psSession
        Copy-Item -Path $installerPath -Destination $destinationPath -FromSession $Using:psSession -Recurse


     } #closing 2nd if
     else {

     write-host "folder already exists"

     } #closing 2nd else

      } #closing 1st if

      else {

     write-host "$Using:file already exists"
      } #closing 1st else

   } #closing invoke command

} #closing foreach statement
```

I tried multiple scenarios using New-Session and Invoke-Commands..too many attempts and changes in my code to share. I even tried to use -FromSession parameter. Thanks again (my first Stack post!) :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello to anyone who sees this. I resolved this issue on my own. What I did was removed both the New-PSSession and the Invoke-Command cmdlets and just used UNC path to connect to my servers in the loop. For ex, I changed path variables to \$server\c$\folder (or "\file"). I did use the Invoke cmd twice within my above script as I needed to run a couple cmds remotely. My revised code is below:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Test,OU=Servers,DC=domain,DC=com" | Select Name -ExpandProperty Name
$username = "domain\user"
$password = "pwd"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password

foreach ($server in $servers) {
Write-host "
Checking server $server
" -ForegroundColor green

```
# First check if the app is installed
Write-host "Checking if the app is already installed
" -ForegroundColor cyan

$fileVerify = "\\$server\C$\Windows\folder\file.exe"
if (!(Test-Path $fileVerify -PathType Leaf)) {

Write-host "File is not on $server
" -ForegroundColor yellow

# Now perform 2 folder checks
$installerPath = "\\$server\C$\foldler\path"
$destinationPath = "\\$server\C$\folder"
if (!(Test-Path $installerPath)) {
    Write-host "$installerPath does not exist. Checking if 1st folder exists...
    " -ForegroundColor yellow

    # Test for last folder
    if (!(Test-Path $destinationPath)) {
    Write-host "$destinationPath does not exist. Creating...
    " -ForegroundColor yellow

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {

        New-Item -Path $Using:destinationPath -ItemType Directory

    } #close 1st invoke

    } #close 3rd if

    else {

    Write-Host "$destinationPath exists, but 2nd folder doesn't.
    " -ForegroundColor green

    } #close 3rd else

} #close 2nd if

else {

    Write-host "$installerPath exists, but the app isn't installed.
    " -ForegroundColor green

} #close 2nd else

# 2 folder checks done, now need to copy 2nd folder & file over
Write-host "Done checking folder structure. Now copying over app folder & file...
" -ForegroundColor yellow

$destinationPath = "\\$server\C$\folder"
$filePath = "\\remote-server\path\to\folder\file.exe"
$sourcePath = "\\remote-server\path\to\folder"
Copy-Item -Path $filePath -Destination $destinationPath -Force
Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath -Destination $destinationPath -Recurse -Force

# All checks are complete, now let's run the app
Write-host "Everything is ready to install the app.
" -ForegroundColor yellow

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {

    Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c C:\path\to\install.bat"

} #close 2nd invoke 

Write-host "The app was installed successfully. Checking next host...
" -ForegroundColor green

} #close 1st if

else {
   
Write-host "The app is on $server. The Client is installed. Checking next host...
" -ForegroundColor green

} #close 1st else
```

} #close foreach

Write-host "All servers have been successfully checked
" -ForegroundColor green

Comment: Sorry about the formatting of my code above. Not sure why it didn't put all of it in 'code form'. I tried editing it a few times, but no luck.